# Who is Anāśritaśiva mentioned in the article?

Tags: shiva, kashmiri-shaivism

Quoting from Swami Lakshmanjoo Maharaj's article on [Why the cycle of the universe is Lord Shiva’s energy](https://www.lakshmanjooacademy.org/bhodapancadashika6-8/):

> “Brahmā, Viṣṇu, Rudra, Iśvara, Sadāśiva and Anāśritaśiva, govern the six states of apanā [subtle internal breath]. These six great beings not only govern these six states in apāna; they govern six states of life also. Childhood is governed by Brahmā, youth is governed by Viṣṇu, old age is governed by Rudra, death is governed by Īśvara, rebirth is governed by Sadāśiva and **liberation is governed by Anāśritaśiva**. Ibid., 6.190.

In the bold part, it says liberation is governed by Anāśritaśiva. Who is he? Which form of Shiva is it?